# What is the difference between install and easy_install for setuptools (setup.py install vs setup.py easy_install)?

Tags: python, setuptools, easy-install

Setuptools has two installation options.

```
python setup.py install
```

There's also:

```
python setup.py easy_install
```

These take different arguments. The documentation here: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools mentions that `install` is mostly a wrapper around `easy_install`, however it does not take the same arguments, for example it lacks the `--always-unzip` and `--allow-hosts` options.

What is the implication of using one instead of the other?